# Url amigavel nao carrega css quando utilizo .php

Tags: url-amigável

Bom pessoal estou aprendendo url amigavel, mas me deparei com um erro que não acho solução, se eu acessar `localhost/farmacia/contato` a pagina é carregada normalmente sem nenhum problema, Mas quando acesso `localhost/farmacia/contato.php` o meu css não carrega fica só HTML puro.

OBS# esse problema se aplica a todas paginas do sistema.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: coloque como esta o link do css, provavelmente voce deve utilizar o link absoluto em vez do relativo

Comment: No caso do absoluto seria `localhost/farmacia/assets/estilo.css`

Comment: Voce esta fazendo dessa forma?

Comment: sim, todo me head onde tem o css e js ta com o caminho absoluto.